# Execute a web api call on creation of file in a folder

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

How can we execute a web api call on a windows server whenever a new file is created on a specified folder

I am thinking of a windows service on server , running on an indefinite loop and lookup for the presence of a file in it.But not very sure about the performance impact. Also in case if the service shuts down automatically the entire assumptions will  fail. So is any other better approaches.

Comment: Can you share what you have researched so far?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani , a windows service on server , running on an indefinite loop and lookup for the presence of a file in a specified folder and if a  file found just process it [ call web api]

Answer (score 1):

Bit long for comment and so thought of posting as answer. So to answer: *How can we execute a web api call on a windows server whenever a new file is created on a specified folder*

> whenever a new file is created on a specified folder

You can use [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class and per documentation

> Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when
>   a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

Thus listen for the event and on handler call your Api endpoint

Comment: Reads more about the FileSystemWatcher , but where we will implement this FileSystemWatcher ? On a windows service and let it runs continuously or do we  have to make some other sort of projects?

Comment: @JibinMathew this answer is a hint, go through this first, research, implement it and if you find some ambiguity than post your question with code snippets.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Any thoughts / suggestions  on project type? is windows service

Comment: @JibinMathew Following is a link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/create-file-watcher-window-service-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: @JibinMathew yes it can be a windows service or even can be a pub/sub one like Zappier

Answer (score 1):

I have built many file processing applications and a windows service is a good option. Instead of a FileSystemWatcher, I would create 3 folders; In, Done and Error. Your service will just need to loop through all the files in the In Folder for processing, then copy them to the Done folder when processed, or error folder if it cannot be processed. This way you can easily see what is done and error and what is left to do. The service will also pick up what is left.

The service class can be pretty lightweight and just call you processing method:

```
namespace App.WindowsService
{
    public partial class FileProcessingService : ServiceBase
    {
        #region System Components

        private readonly System.Timers.Timer _processingTimer;
        private static readonly Logger Logger = Logger.Get();

        #endregion

        #region Service Properties

        private int _interval;
        private bool Stopped { get; set; } = true;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the interval for processing
        /// </summary>
        private int Interval
        {
            get
            {
                if (_interval <= 0)
                {
                    return _interval = Settings.ServiceInterval;
                }

                return _interval;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public FileProcessingService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CanShutdown = true;
            _processingTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            _processingTimer.Elapsed += ProcessingTimerElapsed;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Service Events

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _processingTimer.Interval = Interval;
            _processingTimer.Start();
            Stopped = false;
            Logger.Trace("Service Started");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _processingTimer.Stop();
            Stopped = true;
            Logger.Trace("Service Stopped");
        }

        protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
            OnStop();
            base.OnShutdown();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Processing Timer Elapsed Event

        private void ProcessingTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.MethodEntry();

            try
            {
                _processingTimer.Stop();
                Process();
            }
            // ReSharper disable once EmptyGeneralCatchClause
            catch
            {
            }

            if (!Stopped)
            {
                _processingTimer.Start();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public void Process()
        {
            // Call your processing method
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen any issues with  running a service in background indefinitely on a server? Also is there any chances that the service stops occasionally due to some unknown reasons?

Comment: The main Process method is wrapped in a try..catch to ensure the service will not crash and continue on regardless of errors, it will be best to write an error log when your own method errors. This should ensure the service runs without stopping, We rarely have services stop for no reason.